# Create a child window from a FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, file-watcher

I have a FileSystemWatcher watching for newly created files.

When it sees one, I would like it to open a child window.

Using this:

```cs
private void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    TableWindow win = new TableWindow();
    win.Owner = this;
    win.Text = "xxx";
    win.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    win.Show();
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

After some googling. I ended up with this

```cs
TableWindow win = new TableWindow();
win.Owner = this;
win.Text = "xxx";
win.ShowInTaskbar = false;
win.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    win.Show();
});
```

which gives me a different error:

> Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.

Here's the scenario. on a game, each time a new table is opened, a new file is created. When that file is created, I want to open a child window to display statistics on that table.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Try `this.Invoke(() => win.Show());` Because you want the new Form to associate with the current one, you need to marshal back to current Form's thread

Comment: Thanks Charlieface, I tried it and got an error message  about a delegate.

Comment: Ah sorry you're right, for `Invoke` you need a delegate cast `this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) () => win.Show());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done in the past to work with `InvokeRequired` is to place it within an `if` statement that will call the method on the UI thread if it hasn't been called from the UI thread.

```
private void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    ShowWindow();
}

private void ShowWindow()
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        var del = new MethodInvoker(ShowWindow);
        this.BeginInvoke(del);
        return;
    }
    TableWindow win = new TableWindow();
    win.Owner = this;
    win.Text = "xxx";
    win.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    win.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Nate. It worked like a charm :)